# Is it compulsory to have any class name same as file name in java?

Tags: java, class

```
class test1{
 public static void main(String args[]){
 System.out.print("test successful!");
 }}
```

My file name for the java file was test.java. When I compiled it ,it compliled successfully but while executing it raised an error so I changed the class name from test1 to test that is the file name itself then it executed successfully. So my question is that **IS IT REALL NEEDED TO HAVE ANY ONE CLASS WITH THE SAME NAME AS THE FILE NAME TO BE EXECUTED** in java.

Answer (score 0):

While writing a java program first it is saved as a ".java" file, when it is compiled it forms byte code which is a ".class" file as such that if we made our program file similar to the class it will be comfortable for us to understand without any ambiguity. We are allowed to use any name for a filename only when class is not public. In the case of a public class, we can’t use a different file name.

You can give diff name also, but during run time, you have to mention class name.

Ex-  `test.java`  and has `class Test`

during compile you will write `javac test`
but during runtime you have to mention `java Test`

For complete explanation https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/myth-file-name-class-name-java/

Answer (score 0):

The filename must have the same name as the public class name in that file, which is the way to tell the JVM that this is an entry point.

Suppose when we create a program in which more than one class resides and after compiling a java source file, it will generate the same number of the .class file as classes reside in our program. In this condition, we will not able to easily identify which class needs to interpret by java interpreter and which class containing Entry point for the program.

Read this for more, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/why-the-java-file-name-should-be-always-the-same-as-a-public-class-name